# How can I get Emacs to correctly place auto-saves and backups outside of my source tree?

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

Emacs creates backup files (which I want it to do) but it puts them in my source tree (which I do not want it to do). Following instructions elsewhere, I've placed the following in my .emacs file:

```
    ;; Disable auto save                                                                                                                                                    
    (setq auto-save-default nil)

    ;; Save all tempfiles in $TMPDIR/emacs$UID/                                                                                                                             
   (defconst emacs-tmp-dir (format "%s/%s%s/" temporary-file-directory "emacs" (user-uid)))
   (setq backup-directory-alist
         `((".*" . ,emacs-tmp-dir)))
```

It seems to be ignoring these directives and merrily continues to create the autosave files in the source directories. Any ideas?